# Invalid arguments: The source must not be null

Tags: dart, flutter

I had this app that fetches some data from a remote API. So the data that I am going to receive and display in a JSON `Future`:

`{"status":200,"out":{"summary":[{"bc":"1876","wc":"488679","pc":"731904"}],"last":[{"id":"1877","place":"7","publisher":"-1","bookid":"01877","title":"Neither Civil Nor Servant","author":"Peh","region":"\u65b0\u52a0\u5761","copyrighter":"","translated":"0","purchdate":"2017-04-18","price":"200.00","pubdate":"2016-01-01","printdate":"2016-01-01","ver":"1.1","deco":"\u666e\u901a","kword":"0","page":"220","isbn":"978-981-4642-63-7","category":"","location":"","intro":"TT\u8d60\u4e66\u3002","instock":"1","p_name":"\uff08\u672a\u6307\u5b9a\uff09"}]}}`

I will extract the `out` field from this JSON and assing `summary` and `last` to two variables:

```
initState() async {
    var getter = createHttpClient();
    String uri='http://api.rsywx.com/book/summary';
    var res=await getter.get(uri);
    Map data=JSON.decode(res.body);

    var out=data['out'];

    setState(() {
      _today=formatDate(new DateTime.now());
      _lb=out['last'][0];
      _bs=out['summary'][0];
      _lb['purchdate']=formatDate(DateTime.parse(_lb['purchdate']));
    });
  }
```

So `_bs` and `_lb` are all compound objects.

In my widget `build` function, I will display the contents of these two objects:

```
 new TextSpan(
     text: numFormatter.format(int.parse(_bs['bc'])),
     style: aboutTextStyle,
 ),
```

The program compiles OK but when launched, a quick splash RED screen will appear:

[image]

And soon enough, the correct screen will appear:[image]

I know that during the initial `build`, the object `_bs`, `_lb` is not there yet and the async call to a remote API is still trying to populate the returned response, so in this case, `_bs['bc']` will definitely be not callable. Thus the non-blocking error pops out.

**Workaround**

I can eliminate this error by declaring a bunch of variables and assign them in the `initState` function; instead of rendering `_bs['bc']`, I will render a new variable `_bookCoount`. This way, the rendering will be done without this RED screen and the value of that variable will initially be `null` and soon be the correct value fetched from remote API.

But this is too cumbersome, if you get what I mean: A lot of used-only-once variables.

Or, shall I make the data fetched on the parent level, so that it will be passed to this widget as props? Not tried yet.

Would appreciate your best practice input.

**Update**

The issue really comes from `int.parse`. If I took out that call, the program runs peacefully.

So the question now becomes

I would suppress `int.parse` prompting an error before the value it is going to parse becomes valid.

Comment: If you look in your console you will see much more detailed error reports including a stack trace that shows exactly where the error is.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean with your workaround. In your example `setState()` won't be called before `await getter.get(uri);` returns a value.

I guess this should do

```
 new TextSpan(
     text: _bs != null && _bs['bc'] != null ? [numFormatter.format(int.parse(_bs['bc'])) : 0,
     style: aboutTextStyle,
 ),
```

Comment: This can work around. Better than I declare all the variables.